# Java JFrame to the Front

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

i actually have problems getting my JFrame to the front when i call it.

I have a class inherting from JDialog. It pops up when i start up my 
very cool java game. if i now for example want to load a game i press
the load button and another JDialog opens to choose the game to load.
So i now have to JDialogs open => The startup dialog and the loading dialog.
ok, when i chosed a game and loaded it the load jdialog disposes the JFrame
for the loaded game appears and after that the startup jdialog comes to 
the front again.

I dont want the startup dialog to come to the front!

i already added the following codeline to my JFrame for the game:

```
this.toFront()
```

without any effect.

How can i get my JFrame to the front?

Comment: Do your startup `JDialog` is modal ? If yes, it will ever be on the front. I think use another `JFrame` instead of `JDialog` will resolve your trouble.

Comment: Not modal! the jdialog is just popping back over the jframe after the jframe appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JDialog` objects are supposed to stay on top and will take precedence over any other frames, but if you want to disable that, you can use the following function:

```
jDialog.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
```

You can then call the following function on your `JFrame`:

```
this.toFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are trying to open a JFrame on the click event of load button, you should try the following code on its event handler

```
JFrame o = new JFrame();
  o.setVisible(true);
  dispose();
```

Comment: I dont want the calling component to dispose!
it has to stay open but behind the new JFrame!

Comment: You could toggle its visibility then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you can't interact with your JFrame anymore because the Dialog blocks it. I dont know now what your startup dialog do, but you could put that into a JPanel or a new JFrame!

If you use

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog();
```

you can't interact with your JFrame anymore, first you have to close the dialog.

Make a JPanel and a JFrame and put that what you have in the dialog at your JPanel and open the new Frame if you click on the startbutton.

Comment: No! I dont use JOptionPane i wrote my own JDialogs and they are not modal! The JFrame isnt blocked! The JDialog is just popping over the JFrame and thats very unhandy for the user to switch back to the frame manually